# SpringSource Toolsuite: Huge icons after todays update

Tags: linux, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

im running a linux box with gtk3 and was re-installing my STS today.
I was choosing the x64 version based on eclipse 4.6 and everything went fine after starting the new installed STS version.

Then i decided to check for updates and was installing the suggested packages (i didnt install any own custom packages/plugins yet).
After the restart the GUI seems to be broken. Please see the Screenhot: http://imgur.com/0lAtByT

Im working already since some years with STS on Linux but never found this strange behavior. Anyone a idea what could fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
-Dswt.enable.autoScale=false
```

when starting STS.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. Was already re-installing the latest 4.5.x version and everything seems to be fine. But will try this if i will ever have this problem again....